# php CRUD framework/add-on for CodeIgniter with multi-row edit capability?

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I'm currently using [Grocery CRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/) as my easy-to-implement standard for a basic CRUD system on a CodeIgniter project. I now have a data manipulation use-case in which the ability to edit multiple table/database rows at the same time would be ideal. Basically I'm looking for the Update functionality within the list view. Any PHP framework/add-on suggestions that have this multi-row edit built in?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically for CodeIgniter, but if you're using MYSQL, [LM CRUD](http://lazymofo.wdschools.com/) will work. If you add field names to the grid_input_control array you can edit multiple rows from the grid view.

$lm->grid_input_control['is_active'] = '--checkbox';
$lm->grid_input_control['field_name'] = '--text';